# Filter a multi-column range by the name in the first colum

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I have student data listed across multiple columns.

Column A of the data contains student names.

While each row is specific to a single student named in column A, a single student may have multiple rows of data.

For example, `StudentA`'s name may be listed 8 times, `StudentB`'s 12 times, `StudentC`'s 4 times, and so on.

I want to type a student's name in `F3`, and return the data in `A:B` where the value in column A matches `F3`.

This is my current formula:

```
=IFNA(INDIRECT("A"&MATCH(F3,A:A,0)&":E"&MATCH(F3,A:A,0)-1+MATCH("MYA",INDIRECT("A"&MATCH(F3,A:A,0)&":A"),0)),"Record not found")
```

In this case, I was searching for data for the student `MYA`. I would like it so that I can filter the list for a student without having to hardcode the student's name in the formula as I did above.

## Sample Data

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | **FirstName** | **TestDate** |
| **2** | BLAINE | 04/17/2021 |
| **3** | BLAINE | 04/17/2021 |
| **4** | BLAINE | 04/17/2021 |
| **5** | BLAINE | 04/17/2021 |
| **6** | MYA | 03/01/2022 |
| **7** | MYA | 03/01/2022 |
| **8** | MYA | 03/01/2022 |
| **9** | MYA | 03/01/2022 |
| **10** | IAN | 02/23/2021 |
| **11** | IAN | 02/23/2021 |
| **12** | IAN | 02/23/2021 |
| **13** | IAN | 02/23/2021 |
| **14** | IAN | 02/23/2021 |

## Sample Results

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F | G |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | **FirstName** | **TestDate** |  |  |  |  |  |
| **2** | BLAINE | 04/17/2021 |  |  |  | **Lookup** |  |
| **3** | BLAINE | 04/17/2021 |  |  |  | `MYA` |  |
| **4** | BLAINE | 04/17/2021 |  |  |  | **Results** |  |
| **5** | BLAINE | 04/17/2021 |  |  |  | MYA | 3/1/2022 |
| **6** | MYA | 03/01/2022 |  |  |  | MYA | 3/1/2022 |
| **7** | MYA | 03/01/2022 |  |  |  | MYA | 3/1/2022 |
| **8** | MYA | 03/01/2022 |  |  |  | MYA | 3/1/2022 | **9** | 03/01/2022 |  |  |
| **10** | IAN | 02/23/2021 |  |  |  |  |  |
| **11** | IAN | 02/23/2021 |  |  |  |  |  |
| **12** | IAN | 02/23/2021 |  |  |  |  |  |
| **13** | IAN | 02/23/2021 |  |  |  |  |  |
| **14** | IAN | 02/23/2021 |  |  |  |  |  |

[Link to my demo spreadsheet which you are welcome to edit](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-WjVXNlDIGG1ZeJceOvssW2-vZtAR0MDuUq7J1G6Kmo/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1):

Use `filter()`, like this:

`=filter(A2:E, A2:A = F3)`

See the new [Solution](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-WjVXNlDIGG1ZeJceOvssW2-vZtAR0MDuUq7J1G6Kmo/edit#gid=1419831393) sheet in your sample spreadsheet. There is a [drop-down list](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/186103) in cell `F3`.